Can a solid state relay open and close a ground connection to chassis?
Can I use a solid state relay to open or close a ground connection to chassis?
I need the ground connected to chassis whenever I operate a BLDC motor because it produces a lot of noise and causes loss of communication.
When I am not using the motor I would like to isolate my electronics from chassis ground.

This seems like an XY problem, maybe. What are you trying to accomplish? What happens if you don't float your electronics?

I am trying to isolate my electronics from chassis ground whenever the motor is not being used and I don't want to use a relay because the coil can cause interference with communication.

"I am trying to isolate my electronics from chassis ground whenever the motor is not being used" - why? what's wrong with just having it connected at all times?

it is a downhole tool and at some point I am injecting current to the ground (earth) to produce a magnetic field and locate some pipe and I don't want that current to travel thru the chassis ground of my tool. That's why at some point I want to isolate the chassis ground.

Still not following. If it's connected at only a single point, why would current flow?

A solid-state relay has some voltage drop, and perhaps a minimum working voltage. If you need a really low-impedance path, use an electromechanical relay.

Thank you @DrMoishePippik

Using an electromagnetic relay is an appropriate solution.

The flyback diode should effectively suppress EMI resulting from relay switch-off.

Thank you! That's what I am going to do. I realized that a SSR wont operate without a load, my chassis ground does not has a load.

Anytime, ReneArvi!
